# Is stochastic raytracing inherently cache-unfriendly?

Tags: caching, optimization, raytracing, raycasting, stochastic

Specifically in the context of a real-time raytracer where view updates are frequent?

The obvious answer would seem to be "yes" and yet I wonder if any methods have been found to accelerate Monte Carlo methods given their usefulness.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it seems that if sampling is done using jitter, the coherency is maximized.  As opposed to randomly picking points to sample anywhere.

Comment: Hi Vaughn. Can you offer a source for this?

Comment: This was just an idea off the top of my head.  Do you mean sample source code?

Comment: Oh right. No, what I meant was eg. a paper where this jitter is described. Are you referring to localised jitter in ray packets?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a common technique, but I'm having a hard time finding a good example.   I mean jitter where you break up the pixel into a grid of n cells and then do a random sample within each cell -- as opposed to just doing n random samples within each pixel.  If you process adjacent cells then this should increase coherency.

Comment: Ah. You're probably right. Just that sub-pixel sampling is not even remotely a possibility for me, given I'm working on a fast real-time renderer. However your comment is pertinent to the question, so thank you. I'm not averse to learning as much as possible about this field, which I am still new to.

Comment: Where does the Monte Carlo method come into play in your ray tracer?

Comment: Blurred depth of field is what I'd need MC for. See last picture on [this page](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e9907459/sw_rendering.html).

Comment: I imagine if you want to do fast depth of field you would need to do the blurring as a post-process, similar to how it is done with hardware rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean by stochastic stochasting sampling (for simulating effects like DOF or motion blur), the answer is probably yes. Two sample rays for a same pixel could lead to two very different paths in your acceleration structure, leading to potential cache misses.

One of the best way to accelerate this is simply not to use raytracing for primary rays but rasterization and use stochastic sampling of your polygons (check for [Reyes rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reyes_rendering)).
That's what softwares like Pixar's RenderMan® do for instance.